# Exclude generated classes from sonarlint analysis

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, sonarlint, sonarlint-intellij

When I run the `sonarlint` analysis, unwanted generated classes are also analyzed (R.java, classes generated by Dagger, etc.). It doesn't happen when I run the Android Studio `Analyze -> Inspect code...`.

How can I specify a specific scope for the sonarlint analysis or exclude generated files ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SonarLint issue tracker has the open feature request for that:

- [Configure in IDE files to exclude from analysis](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SLI-97)

More details can be found [here](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/MMF-394).

Comment: why is it only for automatic builds ?